# Moderator election candidate score badge breakdown

Tags: support, badges, moderator-election, candidate-score

In the [moderator election](https://stackoverflow.com/election) nominee section, the candidate score contains the following badge categories:

[image: candidate score badges]

These categories do not exactly follow the ones listed on the [badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) page, for example there is no editing category. Also, participation has 2 gold badges and 7 silver badges which does not add up to the 6 on the candidate score, so clearly only certain badges are considered.

What is the breakdown of these categories i.e. which badges belong to which categories?

Comment: Related on MSE - http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/247138/164200

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### Moderation (3 gold, 4 silver, 1 bronze)

- [Civic Duty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/32/civic-duty) (silver)
- [Cleanup](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4/cleanup) (bronze)
- [Deputy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1002/deputy) (silver)
- [Electorate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/155/electorate) (gold)
- [Marshal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1298/marshal) (gold)
- [Reviewer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1478/reviewer) (silver)
- [Sportsmanship](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/805/sportsmanship) (silver)
- [Steward](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2279/steward) (gold)

#### Editing (1 gold, 2 silver, 3 bronze)

- [Copy Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/223/copy-editor) (gold)
- [Explainer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4368/explainer) (bronze)
- [Organizer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/5/organizer) (bronze)
- [Refiner](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4369/refiner) (silver)
- [Strunk & White](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/12/strunk-white) (silver)
- [Tag Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/254/tag-editor) (bronze)

#### Participation (4 silver, 2 bronze)

- [Constituent](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1974/constituent) (silver)
- [Convention](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/901/convention) (silver)
- [Enthusiast](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/71/enthusiast) (silver)
- [Investor](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/219/investor) (bronze)
- [Quorum](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/900/quorum) (bronze)
- [Yearling](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/13/yearling) (silver)

Thanks @bluefeet for letting me know [there is a tooltip](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/247138/164200). Every candidate with 20/20 has these badges listed, so it appears to be exact.