# How is candidate score calculated?

Tags: discussion, moderator-election, candidate-score

I know there is probably a duplicate floating around the web somewhere, but all my searches couldn't turn up how exactly candidate score is calculated. Is it based on badges? Reputation? Both?

Comment: Both.  Half reputation, half badges: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/247138/160551

Comment: @Troyen Is this: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/17671/how-much-experience-should-a-potential-moderator-have/17674#17674 (referenced in the post) accurate?

Comment: I believe so (also quoted in Shog's answer).  You can also hover over each item and check the tooltip to see how many points each item generated.

Comment: Related for the badge part: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289468/moderator-election-candidate-score-badge-breakdown.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Quoting [my answer on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252641/what-are-the-details-on-the-candidate-score-which-shows-during-an-election/252643#252643):

> The Candidate Score can range from 0 to 40, and is calculated as
> follows:
>
> - 1 point for each 1000 reputation up to 20,000 reputation for a maximum of 20 points.
> - 1 point each for Moderation badges - [Civic Duty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/32/civic-duty), [Cleanup](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4/cleanup), [Deputy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1002/deputy), [Electorate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/155/electorate), [Marshal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1298/marshal), [Reviewer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1478/reviewer),
>   [Sportsmanship](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/805/sportsmanship), [Steward](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2279/steward) - for a maximum of 8 points.
> - 1 point each for Editing badges - [Copy Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/223/copy-editor), [Explainer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4368/explainer), [Organizer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/5/organizer), [Refiner](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4369/refiner), [Strunk and White](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/12/strunk-white), [Tag
>   Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/254/tag-editor) - for a maximum of 6 points.
> - 1 point each for Participation badges - [Constituent](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1974/constituent), [Convention](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/901/convention), [Enthusiast](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/71/enthusiast), [Investor](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/219/investor), [Quorum](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/900/quorum),
>   [Yearling](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/13/yearling) - for a maximum of 6 points.
>
> For badges that can be awarded multiple times only 1 point is granted
> for each badge type, thus ensuring a maximum score of 40 points.
>
> Stats are calculated based on the current state of the candidate, so
> scores on past elections will *not* reflect the state of the
> candidates at the time the election was run.

Want to see how you stack up? [Add your userID to this query on SEDE to see how you rate against the current 12 candidates in the 2016 election!](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/298418/candidate-score?UserIds=260990%2C584192%2C2301450%2C3160466%2C5389107%2C189134%2C4099593%2C476%2C541136%2C1065190%2C561731%2C1835379) (data accurate as of Monday morning)

Comment: Would be nice if there was an official "score calculator" function that was only enabled for reply previews of election threads (i.e. you only get to see your score if you're eligible to nominate yourself for a mod position).

Comment: Follow up question: Suppose, out of curiosity, I wanted to know my candidate score. Is there a shortcut way of calculating it? Say I'm lazy and don't want to go through the trouble of manually (checking badge progress) doing it..

Comment: Ok, I put together [a query on SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/298418/candidate-score?UserIds=1530814%2C3622940%2C1252759%2C871050%2C572%2C1234256%2C1065190%2C492405%2C616460%2C224988%2C3366929%2C465378%2C229044%2C1380752%2C100297%2C1849664%2C189134%2C542517%2C2371861%2C2581872%2C109702%2C3001736%2C1069068%2C476%2C995926%2C1952862%2C2876565%2C379693%2C1603234) for you, @asprin

Comment: Thanks. The score turned out to be quite embarrassing really :)

Comment: @Shog9 Is the same stats used EVERY election?

Comment: How long does this take to update?  I got the Marshal badge a couple of  days ago and my candidate score query remains the same as it was before.

Comment: SEDE is updated weekly, @Richard. Your badge was awarded roughly a day and a half [after the last update](http://data.stackexchange.com/help#faq); you'll see it reflected in your score next Sunday.

Answer (score 9):

Complementary to @Shog9's above query, here's one that will show you all of the moderator election-relevant badges that specified users do or don't have:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1263693/moderator-election-badges