# Improve the election candidate badge score tooltips

Tags: discussion, feature-request, moderator-election

Currently we have [this very useful breakdown](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289501/how-is-candidate-score-calculated/289504#289504) + SEDE query of what badges contribute to a moderator candidate's score. There's now also a tooltip on each section of the candidates' profiles that tells us their score.

I believe the two can be combined to make something MOAR BETTAR:

[image: Moderator badge mockup]

Each of the "badges" list items becomes a JavaScript link that uses `cursor: help` as a visual aid. When clicked, these open a popover with the respective badges, and an indicator next to them to show whether the candidate has that badge or not. The badge names also become clickable links (with `target="_blank"`) that take you to the badges' respective pages on SO. Clicking outside the popup closes it.

(My simple mockup just uses an absolutely-positioned `div` and some checkboxes, but I'm sure someone with a little more talent in the design department can make it look less hideous.)

Like, hate, meh?

Comment: Upvotes but no answers?

Answer (score 3):

Well, I obviously can't edit the Stack Overflow rendering engine, but I do have a userscript (for Greasemonkey and Tampermonkey) that will do basically what you want.

[**Source**](https://gist.github.com/edcottrell/c92d168dd51badc67686)

[**Download Link to Install Script**](https://gist.github.com/edcottrell/c92d168dd51badc67686/raw/75a60f568525e5302086e2679e86cf6095828d83/StackOverflowElectionBadgeViewer.user.js)

When you hover over a badge type, you will get something like this:

[image]

**Note:** This does not yet offer links to the badge pages. If this answer gets enough support in terms of upvotes and/or comments, I will add that.

Feedback and bug reports are appreciated!

---

**Edited** as follows:

Release Log:

```
0.1.0    Initial Release
0.2.0    Suppress title attribute on hover to prevent overlapping tooltips
```

Comment: Please make it suppress the normal tooltip as well; two overlapping tips are distracting.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Done.