# Showing reputation >= 20k

Tags: feature-request, reputation, moderator-election, candidate-score

When I try to cast my vote, I find it pretty hard to know the exact reputation of SO election candidates. The page is showing reputation >= 20k instead of the exact one (the exact reputation was 90k). I have to go to each and every profile to check out the reputation details.

My request is to change this and please show more specific reputation to make it more user-friendly.

[image]

It should at least show >=30k, >=40k, etc.

Comment: How is "show reputation of the candidate" more "user friendly"? We already have a score that resumes a candidate activity on the site which takes into account stuff that normally isn't that visible.

Comment: **Reputation is not important when choosing moderators**. The `>=20k` is meant to deemphasize reputation.

Answer (score 30):

If you really need to know the exact reputation of each moderator candidate, you're probably doing something wrong.

Moderation skill has very little correlation with reputation<sup>1</sup>. For example, as I write this, I have about half of the moderation badges, including nearly all of the *editing* badges, and I have <2K rep. Now take [Jon Skeet](//stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet). He has over 900K rep, has been on the site for 8 years, and has *only recently earned the Marshal badge*. In other words, it took Jon Skeet, who has 600x as much rep as I do, 8 years to do what took me 6 months, 3 of which I rarely logged in.

Really, it maxes out at 20K because that's when [the last moderation privilege](/help/privileges/trusted-user) is earned—20K users know how deletion, protection, etc. *works*.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Okay, I guess maybe on [Community Building](//communitybuilding.stackexchange.com)… but we aren't Community Building.</sub>

Comment: Actually, the last moderation privilege is earned at 10K. Reputation is somewhat relevant; someone with very little reputation also has very little experience with how the site works, and has not spent enough time participating in the site. It's probably irrelevant whether a mod candidate has 20K or 50K rep, that's a big difference over whether they have 2K or 5K.

Comment: Answer deletion doesn't kick in until 20K, and experience there is probably somewhat helpful @Ken.

Comment: @Shog9: Yep. It's clearly been a while since I looked at the privileges page. :-) It seems I missed some of them.  Experience is definitely necessary though, which is the gist of my previous comment. But once you've reached the level of 20K, differences in rep aren't as relevant in regard to moderation skills - you have the experience necessary to know how the site works and for others to be able to evaluate your participation and capabilities.

Comment: Yep. After 20k, you *can* do pretty much anything... So what counts is what you *have* done.

Answer (score 8):

That's not the point of it.  Your total reputation adds into the overall *candidate score*, [which has a specific formula](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/289504/1079354).

The pertinent portion to that regarding reputation is:

> 1 point for each 1000 reputation up to 20,000 reputation for a maximum of 20 points.

So, if a user has 12,000 reputation, they'd get 12 points.  In the example you cite, the user has *at least* 20,000 reputation, so they get the full 20 points.