# Rethinking Moderator Candidate Score for SO

Tags: discussion, moderator-election, candidate-score

> **NOTE**: There are going to be some who think this is about one particular candidate. I have thought about this for several election cycles, based on my own election experience and those I have watched run. Do not make this about one candidate please.

I've wanted to address what has been a fairly arbitrary process of helping people decide who should be elected as a diamond moderator. Let's talk a bit about the nuts and bolts first. In order to run on SO, you must [meet the minimum requirements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135361)

- 3000 reputation
- Civic Duty, Strunk & White, Deputy, Convention badges
- 18+ years old
- Not suspended anywhere on the SE network in the last year

Breaking down the four required badges

- [Civic Duty](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/32/civic-duty) - 300 up/down votes
- [Strunk & White](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/12/strunk-white) - 80 posts edited
- [Deputy](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/1002/deputy) - 80 helpful flags
- [Convention](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/901/convention) - 10 Meta SO posts with +2 score or better

I think we need to acknowledge something important about voters: most people never bother with the "meta" of a candidate. The election page gives you a [candidate score](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/289504/2370483), and for most, that is all many voters will ever really base their votes on. The current candidate score isn't bad, but it's really dated. There are 40 points total, and half of those points are made up by reputation, with the remainder being various badges you can earn by being a "well-rounded community member".

## Reputation

20,000 reputation is not uncommon. As of this writing, we have over 10,000 users above that level (nearly 90,000 users are eligible under the 3k limit). 3k will get you most of the "core" earned non-diamond moderation privileges

- Edit with no approval needed
- Close/reopen votes
- Access to all review queues

The chances a 3k user makes it very far as a candidate under the current system are... pretty low. The lowest reputation moderator I know of would be [Undo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1849664) (didn't win, but was called up due to high demand in the *second* 2015 election). The one person I would have liked to have won with low reputation was [ArtOfCode](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/364502/2370483). He [came in 10th](https://www.opavote.com/results/5229219307061248/0), and I strongly suspect it was largely due to his reputation (around 5k). In other words he was missing a whopping 15 points of candidate score (about 38%). We'll come back to why Art would have made an excellent mod in a later section.

We often debate the efficacy of reputation and votes, but all it really tells us is

1. This person has posted
2. A fair number of people found said posts useful

We're missing any real measurement of a moderator. There needs to be a minimum reputation to run (you have to actually use the site you're about to moderate, after all), but the way candidate score works, that minimum might as well be 20k.

## Badges

Badges are more useful than reputation here, but still lacking overall. I have no idea what [Sportsmanship](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/805/sportsmanship) has to do with being a diamond moderator, yet it's a point on the scoreboard (and I have no idea why Shog9 classified it as a "moderation" badge at that. It's 100% a participation badge).

Some badges are highly useful in [that list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/289473/2370483) (i.e. Steward, Quorum, Marshal) but some are not (i.e. Enthusiast, Yearling, Investor). I think badges have a role to play, (and provide a better picture of a candidate as a potential moderator), but still need work. 20 was a nice round number, so the number of the badges was 20 (19 was [right out](https://youtu.be/xOrgLj9lOwk?t=83)).

## We need engaged candidates

The real problem here is that we're only kind-of sort-of measuring moderation engagement, in a very loose sense. The system works well enough on smaller SE sites, but SO gets *all the flags*. An SO moderator can handle more flags in a day than most smaller SE sites see in a year ([I am not exaggerating](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/374784/244695)). If you're not very engaged before you run, how engaged will you be after? That's part of why we have the Meta questionnaire now as part of the election system (and not a clunky set of Meta posts the candidates have to self-link to).

That's why the participation badges are useful. They just don't give a very good picture of how engaged you already are. The system links to a candidate's Meta posts and reviews, but we leave it to the voter to know why that's important, let alone what they're looking at. Unless we tell the voters these metrics directly, they are unlikely to look.

Coming back to ArtOfCode, his candidate score did not reflect anything he did for the community at large. What does he do? [Charcoal](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq). It's a community-run anti-spam project. Did you know SO has been hammered of late with fake phone support number spam? If you didn't, Charcoal was a big reason for that and Art was integral in helping to set that up. With that territory came lots of helpful flags and a decent amount of review queue work. That's not to say the people he ran against were slouches ([Jean-François Fabre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6451573/jean-fran%c3%a7ois-fabre), who came in 9th in that same election certainly wasn't), but it's hard to be a highly engaged user and come in behind someone who has been hardly engaged at all.

## TL;DR What do you propose?

I propose for future candidate scores should be out of 40 points:

**Editing - 5 points**

We already require 80 edits. Above 80 edits, you can earn 1 point per edit not done on your own post for every 40 edits. That means a 5/5 will need 280 edits. Moderators often suspend bad reviewers in this realm. You need to know how to make good edits.

**Flagging - 10 points**

We already require 80 *helpful* flags. As with editing, you can earn another 1 point for every 20 helpful flags. That means a 10/10 will need 280 helpful flags. We do need to break this down a bit (comment flags can easily run that total up), so no more than half of this score will be for comment flags. You can earn all 10 in post flags, however.

**Meta Stack Overflow Engagement - 5 points**

We already require 10 +2 Meta posts. You can earn 1 point by having 10 non-deleted comments in the last 90 days, another 1 for at least 10 post votes in the last 90 days, and 1 point for having two additional +2 meta posts (at six +2 meta posts you would gain 3 points, or 16 posts total). Voters wouldn't see a breakdown of this, but candidates would.

**Reviews - 20 points**

We have no shortage of [reviews](https://stackoverflow.com/review) to be done. Moderators handle many types of flag. It's not ALL diamond moderators do, but the queues are a lot of our work (Community Managers will notice if the queue gets too large). The breakdown here would be as follows

- 10 points - 1 point per 100 reviews (up to 1000) in the last 90 days. That's an average of 12 or so reviews per day. This counts across all queues, so you can do them all in one queue, or mix it up.
- 5 points - 1 point per Steward badge (1000 reviews), max of 5. Again, you can do them all in one queue or in different queues
- 5 points - 1 point per 100 Low Quality Answers review, max of 5. We get the most of these (not counting comments and moderator flags). If you've done the 500, you should have a decent idea of what an answer should and shouldn't be. These reviews can count toward the other totals. Remember, moderator deletion can't be undone, except by another diamond.

---

These are all **preliminary ideas**. I'm hoping to spark some conversations that will lead to a better rating system for SO candidates. Do we need more points? Fewer? Other criteria not considered?

Comment: Didn't even need to read the post. Based off the title I knew this was gunna be a +1. Now that I have read it... it's still +1, because I can't do +2 :p

Comment: That said, and I don't have time to write an answer, I'd like to see some kind of minimum requirement for restricting people with problematic review histories. Such as repeated suspensions in recent history, suspensions due to blatant disregard of the rules on things that should be clear, such as obvious plagiarism or vandalism/spam, or other similar cases where they've proven themselves unable to perform the tasks of a moderator to a minimum standard.

Comment: To me, the arguments would be more persuasive without the parts about the merits of a particular candidate. Why are they mentioned at all?

Comment: It would be an even clearer picture of the candidate if the score weren't capped. One who has edited 30.000 posts obviously contributed more than on who edited 280. And most importantly it shows consistency over time.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny to make it clear where the old score fails and how the new score works better by giving a concrete example. Else we'd get questions like "but why do we need a new score at all? I'm not persuaded." Since it's impossible to satisfy everybody, a practical approach seems to make sense.

Comment: I kind of like what @blackgreen is saying.  I think maybe the ONLY metric that should be capped is the rep points -- this can really start to balloon once you have posted a few thousands times, whereas curations activities never offer residual returns.  I like not capping curation statistics.  Greater Meta representation on candidate score cards is definitely something that I support.

Comment: Regarding helpful flags, I would not count comment flags at all. They just come in too easily. Count total post flags and post flags in the last 90 days.

Comment: Excellent ideas! Certainly regarding having some metrics that show _recent_ and not total activity. For the _last 90 days_ metrics, that should be preceding 90 days before the start of the election to avoid people padding their score by suddenly engaging on meta for example, and to prevent unexpected score changes during the election

Comment: I agree with most of your suggestions. However, for the 20 points awarded for reviewing, I think it would be a good idea to only award points for each review where the majority of reviewers agree with you (similar to how the [Consensus](https://winterbash2021.stackexchange.com/consensus), [Rapport](https://winterbash2021.stackexchange.com/rapport) and [Harmony](https://winterbash2021.stackexchange.com/harmony) hats worked in Winter Bash). This would hopefully give good reviewers more points than bad reviewers.

Comment: Also, in case the company doesn't want to put too much effort into this, I think that at the very least the current candidate score should be rounded up to the next multiple of 5 or 10. It makes no sense to me that a candidate should lose an election just because they're missing one badge.

Comment: It would be more useful for people that actually take an interest in the candidates if the metrics were dynamic, ie a sede query where people can change the timespan to see if moderation has increased just for the election or consistent

Comment: Having said that I’m not sure if anything would make a difference where I’d bet that 90% of the voters are doing it for a free badge and just pick the first 3 to appear on the screen

Comment: @NickstandswithUkraine I had thought about that but there's two problems with trying to limit people with review suspensions. The first is only mods can see your review suspensions (full suspensions are public). The second is we don't want to make people risk-averse to reviewing. I see review suspensions (most of which are automatic) as guide rails to better reviewing (and it usually works). If someone had a seriously bad history of reviewing we might object, but such people are rare (such as the 6 folks with a review suspension longer than a year).

Comment: @Machavity That makes sense, glad to hear you at least considered it :-)

Comment: I think the candidate score should be out of 1000 instead of 40, and a lot more should go into it! About: "Did you know SO has been hammered of late with fake phone support number spam? If you didn't, Charcoal was a big reason for that", can you be more specific about what you mean by "phone support spam"? The fact that I'm asking this might mean that Charcoal is working, but I also think you could be more descriptive because I can't even **imagine** what you might mean by "phone support spam". Also: helping build charcoal was greatly beneficial but doesn't mean the author will be a good ♦mod.

Comment: @user1271772 https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/413187/stopping-the-s-upportnumber-%ef%b8%8f-adver-tising-cmpai-gn-spam

Comment: Controversial opinion perhaps: why are we scoring candidates at all? What other elections do we have where a candidate gets a score before the race has begun? I agree with a minimum criteria being present, that's a no-brainer, maybe even making it a little more stringent, but scoring makes me feel uncomfortable.

Comment: @DavidG **I totally agree with DavidG** The scores and rep on display just make it easier for people to vote for people with higher numbers in those categories without actually knowing the candidates or reading the answers to their questions! Why don't you write an answer to this question, suggesting to have no candidate score or rep shown at all? I'd support that answer!

Comment: @NickstandswithUkraine I still don't get it. That Meta post is quite confusing, especially the title. Why not just say: "Did you know that we've had an influx of spam from Coinbase lately?"

Comment: I like ArtOfCode a lot but cannot follow the conclusion in this question. He programmed a lot for tools that fight spam and that would make him a good moderator on SO. How? I thought moderators need time and wisdom in handling flags, not programming skills. Or do moderators here have to write their own tooling? The example does not seem to be an apt one. Apart from that I don't really like the candidate score. It's as useful as rep (and half it's rep).

Comment: @Trilarion Art was someone highly involved in moderation on SO (he still is involved, just [elsewhere on SE](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/users/98/artofcode)). My point is that, while he might not have won with a different candidate score, I don't think he fared well because the candidate score obscured his contributions. You've reiterated my biggest gripe: reputation. I know 3k users that would make for decent mods. I don't encourage them to run because they'd be missing nearly half the points in the only metric many voters seem to go by.

Comment: "highly involved in moderation" You mean by programming? I don't know if that is what a moderator needs to know here. If there was a single value that would capture the suitability for being a moderator, we could even skip the voting phase, but there isn't. And the best way to avoid people going for simple but misleading scores is not to show them these. Please, don't try to construct yet another not very useful score.

Comment: Why shouldn't "Yearling" be a useful badge? Would we want someone to moderate who is a member for less than a year? Can someone know the site in less than a year? I'm a member for 11 years and sometimes I think I still don't know how it works (but maybe it just changed)

Comment: _"19 was right out"_ I love that I don't have to click the link to know exactly what the reference is :D

Comment: this resembles ancient proposal of [citizenship level](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/165305/165773)

Comment: I don't agree that ArtOfCode is a good moderator candidate because they were (and are) integral for setting up charcoal; that is not a valid argument in my book (they might be for other reasons though, but that's what elections are for so there is no need to go into details here about specific people). We need moderators and we need people that automate processes so moderators are less necessary; the two do not by definition overlap.

Comment: The main problem right now isn't so much the various prerequisites but rather that very few people like to do unpaid, boring busy-work for some soulless, Twitter-driven private company in the US. If this was some manner of community primarily here for the benefit of mankind, that would have been a different story, but SO has moved very far away from that. Why people still sign up to run for mod elections is truly beyond me.

Comment: I don't think this really... solves the problem. It just creates the same problem only the score/benefit is tilted toward a different (much smaller) group of users.

Comment: @KevinB you said it wonderfully.

Comment: "*Enthusiast, Yearling*" I think these are mildly useful for moderator candidacy: some users can earn reputation *very* quickly... I have seen some users who get to 20k reputation in less than three months on the site. They spend all their time answering questions, which is impressive, certainly, but they have had _no_ time to get to know the various moderation abilities in that short time span... The **Yearling** badge shows that someone has been around long enough to learn the ropes, perhaps dip their toes in activities that have long-standing precedent but little in the way of written rules

Comment: Likewise, someone who has earned reputation and badges in general may be a good user of the site, but if they only drop in once a week or so, that's not great for onboarding a new moderator... which usually happens out of a _need for more moderation help_ ... in other words, a new mod being AFK for 90% of the time each week isn't going to be much help. The **Enthusiast** badge shows they have the ability to make a daily commitment to visiting the site (though I fully acknowledge it has its shortcomings... miss one day and the other 29 of the month count for naught!).

Comment: Totally agree with you on Sportsmanship and Investor badges, though. Those are totally participation badges... it's nice to know potential mod candidates are able to let go of some rep or be a team player instead of a rep hog, for sure, but there are so many other things that are more important.

Comment: @Dharman I am quite biased, admittedly (the vast majority of my flags these days are comment flags) but I don't like that restriction re: not counting comment flags. Flags are flags... if they are helpful, they should be counted. I agree answer flags require more effort to put into, but a large amount of the flags mods handle are comment flags... experience in knowing which ones to mark helpful or not is useful.

Comment: @Machavity In the same vein perhaps as Dharman's suggestion above re: comment flags or not... I might suggest considering discounting tag-only edits in the edit metrics. They are useful, but much less so than editing a post's body or title to improve it.

Comment: "*You can earn 1 point by having 10 non-deleted comments in the last 90 days*" Why the severe time-based restriction here? It's not clear if this is new to your suggestion or if it's currently an undocumented aspect of how the relevant badge works... As far as I know, comment badges count all comments ever... even if it takes you two years. Not that I'm _against_ such a restriction, necessarily... I'd just like to hear the justification _for_ the time restriction (and for why it is set to 90 days instead of, perhaps, 180 days or something a bit more forgiving).

Comment: @DavidG Without a score, elections become *purely* a popularity contest. The point of the score is to provide a grading rubric against which to grade a potential candidate. The scores translate (roughly) to how good a candidate a user will be on paper... this post seems to be an attempt to improve that grading rubric to be more accurate/relevant given what we've learned over the last ~10 years of elections about what works and what doesn't in terms of candidate score (especially as the user populations have changed... in 2011, how many users had 20k+ reputation? Compared to >10,000 users now?)

Comment: @DavidG Candidates and politicians get scored all the time.  Group A will score them on how good their stances are for the environment, Group B will score them on how friendly they are towards unions, Group C will score them based on how much their voting record matches their election promises, etc.

Comment: @TylerH "this post seems to be an attempt to improve that grading rubric to be more accurate/relevant" It may fail to be more accurate/relevant for example by going into another extreme direction and if the problem is that people anyway vote only by score than the existence of any score might be problematic by itself. I think this here might be a better score than the previous, but I'm not really sure we need scores at all. The benefit might be limited.

Comment: @Trilarion So I would say again... without some kind of score, elections become _purely_ a popularity contest. Unless you are envisioning some other, non-numerical way to measure a candidate's aptitude, like a speech or written response? (Personally I would like _both_ a comprehensive stats breakdown/score **and** a short exposé on why they ought to be voted for...)

Comment: @TylerH Maybe we mean the same. In an answer below I advocate for everything but a single score. A comprehensive summary of the stats is fine, an application expose we already have, but a single score will always give this single score a lot of weight, probably too much. Elections should even be popularity contests I think. That's how I know it from real life. But saying, here we already ranked candidates by how we think they should be ranked, now you vote freely on them ... isn't good I think.

Comment: @Trilarion A score is not the same as a rank (and how would you handle ties?) Candidates appear in a different order every time you load the elections page during an election. We also have to rank them manually when deciding who to vote for. Those two things _should_ make it clear to users that the score is not a rank.

Comment: @TylerH A single score implies an ordering and that implies a ranking (ties simply result in equal ranking). If voters simply go by score (as Machavity claims) they do exactly this, sort the random order of the elections page by score in their head and then vote for the highest score because highest score means best in the ranking. Every single score is a ranking and I agree with Machavity - voters indeed used that score to rank candidates. This is not good and should better be abolished completely than only tweaking it in another direction.

Comment: Should asking good questions be on the list? Only one of the current crop of candidates has asked more than a handful of questions in the past few years.

Comment: Posting content is orthogonal to moderators' day-to-day duties, @Dave. Nothing can be concluded about a candidate's fitness to be a mod from how many posts they made (well, apart from posting *a lot* being actually a red flag of not using the closure system enough). Not to mention that knowledgeable people tend to only *answer* without ever having the need to ask a question.

Answer (score 52):

I love MUCH of what you are suggesting, but I do have a couple of suggestions/concerns.

1. Your calculations are mixing between "all-time" efforts and efforts within the last 90 days. I'm actually interested in seeing both the "in the last 90 days" and "all-time" scores for all metrics for all candidates.  A tabular breakdown would help me to understand the candidates better.
2. How would the last few elections have looked if they used your score calculations?  What we should really strive to see is **differentiation** between candidates.  It ends up being entirely unhelpful if all candidates have maxed out card scores -- then voters will either need to go on a self-led statistical safari, or more likely, they'll take the lazy route and just pick the person(s) that they are most familiar with.

No matter what metrics are eventually used, I am in favor of relying less on unicorn points and relying more on participation/reviewing/curation activities.

I hope this marks a strong start to revolutionized candidate cards for future elections.

P.S. If we are scrutinizing the users' "last 90 days", then I would expect at least 80 days of logins.  I believe Stack Overflow mods should be Fanatical.

Comment: Yeah, the 90 days was more an attempt at keeping the actions relatively recent. I freely admit the time is arbitrary just for the sake of discussion. I did see a candidate once who had not done any reviews for a very long time and then did enough to ensure their front page of reviews was recent before nominating (they did not win). I should also note I have no real major insights as to how this would affect any elections. I think the current moderator crew would get a 40/40, but I've not been exhaustive in looking either

Comment: Would 365 days be better than 90?  Or 180-ish?  I agree that relatively recent activity is important.  I've done reviewing in the past (5+ years ago); I've not done much recently.  I do my bit by editing and commenting to get edits made.

Comment: I could be just as happy with 90, 100, or 120 days.  I like what ErikA said under the question about preventing rushed actions by candidates once an election is announced.  The range of time for recent activity should be _N_ days before the announcement of the election.  Honestly 3 or 4 months should be the most -- you can get a VERY good sense of a user's maintainable contribution volume by seeing their last quarter-year of activity.  I think we get diminishing returns on increasing the range beyond 4 months. (this is in addition to their lifetime achievements.)

Comment: I agree we want mods who are more active than not, but mods _do_ go on leave sometimes, and that is encouraged by the CM team to avoid burnout. So I would simply caution a bit about hard requirements for activity levels... maybe show the statistic, but let users decide if they want to factor that metric in.

Comment: If you're going to require Fanatical then you should also require that moderators receive full-time pay and benefits.

Comment: I never said `require` @Clement.

Comment: @mickmackusa  "I would expect" and "should be" certainly _reads_ like a requirement. Would you support the election of a moderator who does not? A full-time employee (5 days a week) works 64 out of every 90 days. 80/90 is considerably more than full-time. If mods are _expected_ to work more days than a full-time employee, I _expect_ a for-profit employer to give them corresponding pay and benefits. Especially since US labor law requires it.

Comment: @ClementCherlin honestly, I think it's doable to be fanatical. https://imgur.com/a/Hr8Ylz0  Being on-site daily is not the same as working an 8h day.  Mods are only asked to volunteer ~30m per day.  The people I see in SOCVR are there every day and seemingly for longer than 30 minutes.

Answer (score 32):

I like this proposal, but I would like to suggest some changes.

The candidate score should be easy to understand but not so easy that we would be asking voters to rank candidates in descending order of their score. Otherwise, we might just automatically elect the candidates with the highest score. The problem with the current score is that it doesn't convey meaning clearly enough and that it is just a single number. Many eligible voters probably don't care enough to understand what goes into it and just look for the highest number.

Maybe we should have a couple of different scores and don't sum them up together. Showing scores for total moderation activities and activities within the past year, but separately for each category. The categories could be editing, reviewing, flagging, meta. The values should be normalized or presented in an easy to compare way. If we have four candidates with 100 edits each and one candidate with 200, is the one with 200 a much better choice? What if a candidate with 50000 edits shows up? The categories should allow voters to find candidates that proved themselves useful in ways that matter to the voters. Some might care more about editing, some about flagging. Maybe someone is looking for an active meta contributor. We should be able to find the candidate that satisfies our own criteria the best, and not vote on a total candidate score. Maybe something similar to a [skill bar](https://www.google.com/search?q=skill+bars&rlz=1C1ONGR_enIE946IE946&sxsrf=APq-WBsXnPPjYCfQQwCzKnzcCMIAPudCsg:1645880275556&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwik56rptZ32AhXGTcAKHQNjDZ4Q_AUoAXoECBMQAw&biw=2560&bih=1297&dpr=1#imgrc=IgwheVrN0_-LRM) would be useful. It should also not be easy to attain a 100% score across the board.

I would say that the badges are worthless when it comes to the candidate score. The 4 mandatory ones can stay, but the rest should not be used in the election process.

Comment: I think you make an excellent point about the score; there's a balance at play between the score being an altogether useless metric, and it being so "useful" that it may as well be the de facto ranking of candidates. I think it should be more useful than it currently is, but I really like your idea of making it less a "ranking" or "scorecard" and more just data to take in regarding the candidates. A ranking tells people how they should vote outright; stats give voters more information to better inform their _own_ choices.

Comment: I'd like this idea to be a new "fact sheet" page that is accessible during the election for each candidate that displays a large array of data ranging from all forms of moderation history to meta participation with links.

Answer (score 25):

As a recent candidate (who justifiably came in last) I thought much along the lines that you did, and even asked (and answered) a question about the score which was included in the moderator questionnaire.  Some thoughts on your proposal:

### Reputation and Moderator Privileges

I've been on SO over 10 years but the first 5-7 of that was mostly as a consumer of content: someone who found great value in the site's content and loved the ability to find the answers to my questions before asking them.  Even when the answers were outdated or partial, they often gave me enough hints to go in the direction I needed to solve my problems.  But there's no way to measure that side of "participation".  That experience has, however, given me a bias against aggressively deleting content that is at least marginally helpful.

However, for those of us who have become more active in the recent history, it's much harder to gain reputation (without playing [FGITW](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19533#19533)), particularly if we stick to answering questions in our areas of expertise. But does that really measure moderation ability?

The minimum reputation does, however, have an impact in tooling/experience necessary to be a moderator.  While "most" of non-diamond moderator privileges can be awarded to a 3K, there's a strong argument for making the minimum at least 10K, with a demonstrated minimum use of the moderation privileges available there, or perhaps even 15K with an understanding of when to protect questions.  Neither ability or a measure of its use seems to be included in the existing candidate score or in your proposal.

### Flagging and Editing

You highlight the importance of SO moderator flag-handling and arguably this should be the highest component of the score by some measure.  If a moderator is expected to spend a significant portion of their time handling flags, they should demonstrate the ability to know what a good flag looks like.

Your proposal, however, weakens the existing score. The minimum is 80, but the candidate score includes Marshal (500) which seems a reasonable, if not better, measure than your proposal capped at 280.

Similarly the editing minimum is 80, but the candidate score includes Copy Editor (500 excluding own posts or tag edits) which seems a reasonable, if not better, measure than your proposal capped 280.

### Review Queues

I generally like your proposal here.  I was rightly criticized for low review queue participation during the nomination phase, and I'm sure that finding a way to measure both active (and recent) moderation participation alongside the "minimum" requirements of achieving badges is important.  A lot of the minimums (no matter how high they are set) can easily be achieved and then ignored, while queue participation is likely much more of a predictor of being able to handle expected workloads as a moderator.

Answer (score 24):

Just **abolish the candidate score** entirely and attach an automatically created participation list below every candidate's application:

- number of questions asked on main site (and on meta)
- number of answers written on main site (and on meta)
- number of edits on main site (and on meta)
- number of reviews done on main site (and on meta)
- number of flags raised on main site (and on meta)
- ...
- list of relevant badges: all the badges from a pre-defined set of relevant badges

Possibly with rates of positively received questions/answers, rates of helpful flags, etc ...

Maybe also an activity over time histogram for people to judge over how much time these stats were aggregated.

That way you **show the exact engagement** without tempting people to compare a single metric that simply doesn't work in sufficiently describing candidates. Let people have their own weights on the various ways users can contribute. Do not pick a single set of weights and insist everyone must see it.

Comment: Questions asked is not very material; questions answered is IMO a lot more relevant.  I've asked 50 questions; I've answered 12k+ questions.  Coincidentally, Mr Skeet has asked 50 questions, but he has provided about three times as many answers as me.  If the 'questions asked' threshold is suitably low, that might be OK.  I'm thinking of something like a net score of 10 more positively received questions with accepted answers other than self-answers compared with negatively received questions or questions without an accepted answer or self-answered questions. _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ I note that 'acceptance rate' was once a measure on SO, but it got removed a long time ago.  That may make the 'accepted answer' part a bit controversial.  Nevertheless, something closely related to that indicates a potential moderator's attitude towards those who help on SO by providing answers, etc.

Comment: I agree with this. No implementation of the candidate score will be perfect. The current implementation favours reputation, while the proposed one favours reviews. My opinion is that reviews are indeed important, but I also believe that if someone thinks reputation is important, that their vote is equally as important as mine. Rather than tweaking the score, I would remove it and make every interesting metric easy accessible during the election, so providing the numbers you proposed would be a good start.

Comment: This would be the way to go. Unbiased raw data.

Answer (score 21):

Here's my two cents (a bit more than two...).

We need the candidate score to be an easy metric so that voters can understand what it is at a glance and prospective candidates don't need to reach for the calculator to figure out how they'd fare. We also need to show more than one single number, so that candidates aren't simply ranked in descending order based on that.

#### Reputation

**10.000 minimum threshold**<sup>1</sup>: you have some familiarity with *all* user-level moderation tools and access to all review queues. The truth is that it isn't that hard to reach 3k on mid-high traffic tags if you post good stuff. That aside, it's probably easier to get reputation by answering. IMO this is desirable, and upping the requirement to 10k means you have to answer a good bunch of posts.

Why is it desirable? Because by answering you can touch first-hand what an answerable question looks like (hopefully...), have more time to familiarize with close votes and close reasons, have more time to familiarize with close/reopen review queues.

By that logic, 5k or 7k could also be an adequate threshold, but some familiarity with the 10k moderation tools is even better. By poking around in the moderator tools *and by seeing deleted posts* you can get a feeling of what content gets deleted, by whom, ask yourself why, etc.

**Do not give candidate points for reputation**, or give 1 point at most when over 20k (Trusted User). Just don't show the rep on the candidate card. Reputation is really a different metric and shouldn't be conflated with curation. People who value reputation over other stats can simply go to the user's profile.

#### Badges

I propose a substantial overhaul of badge points.

- Remove Sportsmanship. I'll just link to [Dharman's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416220/rethinking-moderator-candidate-score-for-so/416227#416227). If you post in a low-traffic tag, or if you post first answers that are very comprehensive, there may be just nothing else to upvote.
- Remove Investor. Not sure why offering a bounty on someone else's question should count toward a diamond moderator score. It shows you know how to use bounties, and that's about it. You could have offered a bounty on an off-topic question to begin with, and be none the wiser about site moderation.
- Keep Civic Duty (vote 300 times), Cleanup (1 rollback), Electorate (600 votes), Explainer and Refiner (answer&edit), Organizer (1 retag), Tag Editor (1 tag edit), Constituent (voted in an election, you should care about the process you're nominating yourself for), Enthusiast **and not Fanatic** because we need people who log in, without encouraging an excess, and respect the fact that people may have other stuff to do in their lives, and Yearling (shows participation over time, even if it does so in a less-than-ideal way by considering rep earned).
- Add Research Assistant (50 tag edits). It's a rare badge but it shows two important things: 1) you care about tags, and as a moderator you may have to work with tags (retag, burninate, synonimyze) and 2) especially in case of candidates below 20k, you can suggest good tag edits, given the amount of plagiarism that goes around tags. It's just one point on the "Badge" metric, so not too bad if a candidate doesn't have it, but rewards those who do.
- Remove editing, flagging, review and meta badges from this count. Count those separately.

Call the metric "Badges", max score: 10

#### Edits

Detach this from the editing badges. Give 1 point each 100 edits. The purpose is to allow people who don't edit much to have something to show. 450 edits are still a nice contribution, so it'd be 4 points for those who don't have Copy Editor yet.

Call the metric "Editing". I have 663 edits as of today, my "Editing" score would be 6.

- If someone comes along with 20.000 edits, their editing score would be 200. Is it fair compared with my meagre 6? Yes. They edited 19337 posts more than me.
- Should this be capped? Maybe. As with many uncapped things, there is space for abuse. Someone could write a bot that replaces semicolons with colons and go on a spree. However I'd say that abuse of this kind is easy to spot.

#### Flags

Detach this from the flagging badges. Give 1 point each 100 helpful flags on posts.

Here the cap is unnecessary because flags are always reviewed by someone. One who raises bogus flags to inflate their score would be flag-banned, or in severe cases suspended. If the flags are good, then they are making a good service.

Call the metric "Flagging". I have 1360 helpful post flags, so my "Flagging" score would be 13.

#### Reviews

Just count Steward badges. The metric is already there, we just have to show it.

- About weighing different review queues differently, I'm not sure it's worth it. As long as you are doing any reviews, you are providing a service to the community and your candidate points should reflect that.
- About review suspensions, counting Steward badges sort of addresses that too. If you are a bad reviewer and get suspended often, you'll have a hard time getting more Steward badges.

Call the metric "Reviews".

#### Meta participation

- 1 point for Quorum and Convention badges
- 1 point for Pundit badge on meta
- 1 point for each silver and gold question or answer badges (bronze badges are out because it's relatively easier to get upvotes in meta)

Personally I'm not a big fan of expanding this metric, but I understand that some people may put importance on meta participation.

#### What about normalization, ratios, etc.?

I propose to forgo all those. Show candidate metrics for what they are, give people credit for all contributions they made as much as possible.

#### What about recent activity?

I don't think there is a formula that can easily capture this. Any period of time would be arbitrary and unfair to those who did substantial contributions but now have stuff coming up in their life just before the election.

---

So my candidate card would be like:

```
Reputation: <20k
Badges: 9
Editing: 6
Flagging: 13
Reviews: 11
Meta: 8
```

Without max scores in the form `3/10` voters can compare numbers with other candidates instead of against a maximum, and perhaps be prompted to find out more; or simply focus on the metrics that matter to them.

---

<sup>1: since I first wrote this post, I'm no longer so strongly convinced that 10k rep is a desirable threshold. Needs more thought.</sup>

Comment: Are close-votes part of the "Flagging" category? Or aren't they taken into account at all?

Comment: I specifically like and agree with the removal of max scores. As you said, it encourages voters to compare candidates ***to each other***, rather than to some arbitrary maximum...

Comment: @BDL close-votes within the review queue would count for Steward badges, and go in the "Reviews" category. As for organic close votes, that's kinda difficult to count in a meaningful way. You know, like those who close as "Needs More Focus" posts with low effort, or VtC posts that stay open in review

Comment: @blackgreen: Yes, they are hard to count. Maybe just take those were the question has been closed lateron? At least 1/3 of the close-votes are from outside the queues (the one that is pushing the question into the close-vote queue). I, for example have close voted ~5k times, mostly organic or through SOCVR, but I only have 1.3k close vote reviews. So 2/3 of the votes wouldn't count.

Comment: @BDL the intent of my proposal is to keep it simple. Actually I don't do much reviews in the close votes queue either. I mostly filter by my main tag to find pending close votes there, and cast a lot of votes outside of the queues. But I think this is okay for a moderator election. We want to specifically encourage and reward traceable site-wide activity.

Comment: [cont] as a candidate you may choose to include the count of your votes in your nomination post as an additional metric, and I'm sure it will matter to those who care about reading nominations, but I wouldn't include it in the official candidate card

Comment: I like the general idea of these suggestions, although regarding '*If someone comes along with 20.000 edits, their editing score would be 200. Is it fair compared with my meagre 6?*' I don't think this is really that good for edits or flags... they should remain capped. The reason is that some users use scripts to automatically cast flags or make edits and are not involved whatsoever in the effort... it's all automated. Not only would this artificially inflate their score (someone could have 1000 points alone from this), it could *mislead* people into thinking they're an expert editor/flagger.

Comment: And I sat that as someone who would have 370 points from manual/unscripted flags and edits alone as a candidate.

Answer (score 16):

I agree with most points that you have made but have a minor issue with some of your comments on the [Sportsmanship badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/805/sportsmanship):

> Up vote 100 answers on questions where an answer of yours has a positive score.

I believe that this should be included in any moderator candidate score since gaining the badge *suggests* that an individual places a higher regard to answer (and site) quality, than to their own reputation score.

Yes, it is a badge obtained through participation, not moderation, but it highlights what may be important personality characteristics needed in a moderator: altruism as well as someone who cares deeply about the quality of the Q&A's on this site.

Comment: Yeah, but in many tags this is close to impossible. The users who care about quality the most only answer when there is no suitable answer. There is nothing to upvote.

Comment: FWIW, I agree the badge itself is important for what it emphasizes. We're rewarding upvoting useful answers competing with your own. But... I earned mine by combing through old answers of mine right after I nominated. Don't get me wrong: I still only upvoted quality answers. But... I probably wouldn't have done that without trying to get the badge. It's not a very *organic* badge in this context. Sometimes useful competing answers come in much later, long after you've moved on

Comment: The sportsmanship badge heavily favours high traffic tags and/or ones in which many different approaches can solve a problem. If you are answering in a niche tag, it can take quite a bit of waiting time until other users bother to post >= 100 answers. At best the sportsmanship badge is an indicator how popular the topics are you are answering, not some personality characteristics.

Comment: *"the badge suggests that an individual places a higher regard to answer (and site) quality, than to their own reputation score."* - So does downvoting other peoples answers.

Comment: "altruism as well as someone who cares deeply about the quality of the Q&A's on this site" - nice joke... this badge does not require anybody to care about quality, and altruism in regard to upvotes doesn't sound quality-focused either. I'd guess most people get the badge because they _don't_ care about quality but answer every trash question instead of closing it, and upvote everyone who does the same (the misguided "we have to help everyone and be nice" crowd). If you want to find users that care about site quality, look for users with a metric crapton of downvotes and closevotes instead.

Comment: @Dharman I disagree - I have this badge almost exclusively for upvoting answers that came along after mine, that I think are equally as good if not better. After all, many questions have more than one possible solutions and there is nothing to say that mine will be the best.

Answer (score 8):

"How many points per category?" is a question that hides an assumption: that there should be a single answer, distilled from a consensus here. But if you take one step back, this score is something we then feed back to prospective voters in the election.

Shouldn't we put the decision which factors are important back to the voter? We're programmers, we can all imagine how straightforward it is to let voters set weight factors for themselves. Each voter can then see a personalized ranking of the candidates, based on the factors important to that vote.

This just leaves us with the question which factors should be included. `{edit, flag, meta, review}` seems like a workable set.

Comment: I like this idea a lot, it echoes Dharman's answer. I'm all for improving the current score metric, I think there's benefit to having a score system the more accurately reflects being good moderator material– but I think it'd probably be _more_ beneficial to give numbers (plural) that help voters decide _for themselves_ what qualities are most important, rather than handing it to them in a single overall "score" number.

Answer (score 7):

**Shifting around how the score is calculated** doesn't do anything to solve the root issue in that people are more often than not voting based off of a calculated score rather than the individual candidates... instead it plays into it.  All it really does is shift favor from one much larger, easier to be a part of group of users to one much smaller.

Taking half of the score being earned from reputation and moving that to reviews done *in the past 90 days* is pretty drastic. There's varying reasons why people don't review, and they don't all involve not being engaged with moderation.

***I'd suggest instead making the score easier to cap.*** The candidate score should be a soft gate of entry. If one metric of it is too difficult to meet for a significant number of candidates, we should do something about that metric to bring it more in line with the community. If everyone's at "40" or whatever the cap is, then the things setting candidates apart is what they say/do rather than a skewed ranking system.

Comment: I agree that the candidate score, however it's calculated, is not ideal. However, the vast majority of the electorate just look at the visible numbers on the candidate's nomination. Until we do something to get users to actually look at what candidates say/do (and I have no concrete suggestions to effect that change), the candidate score at least *helps*. If we had a soft candidate score that doesn't distinguish between candidates, the rep of the candidate is likely to play an even larger role in the evaluation, which I'm pretty sure you'd agree is a step in the wrong direction.

Comment: Sure, however, i don't feel comfortable with moderators/some group of power users skewing the system to favor people like them/us either.

Comment: I'd rather focus on a user's style of moderation/overall actions, more so than how well they can dodge audits/cater to the intricacies the mess of a review system we have. If we need more moderators because the ones we select aren't handling thousands of flags a week, add more moderators. We're already on a troubling trend of smaller and smaller elections, we don't need to further constrict our candidate pool by making it pointless to run if you haven't done 1000 reviews in the past 90 days.

Comment: Put another way, i think we should be leveling the playing field, not making it more slanted. Give the people actually willing to step up and put their cards on the table the chance to succeed.

Comment: People putting their cards on the table gave me an idea: Let candidates choose their five best contributions to the main site and their five best contributions to the meta site and compile them as a list and attach them to the nomination. This is surely something that voters can check and at the same time doesn't result in simple scoring. You can probably get to know a person really well by reading only a small amount of their contributions if only these contributions are selected well.

Answer (score 3):

I understand why you're against reputation being a major factor in the candidate score, but participation in the *actual* community, not the meta-community, is a very, very important factor in understanding what the community is about.

This isn't to say that you *cannot* be a good moderator without said participation; but just like in any job interview, it is all about the preponderance of the available evidence - and in general, being a participant in the community is a major part of that.

This is probably more relevant on other sites than StackOverflow, but it's a relevant one here *also*.  The bar is not very high, and it doesn't take very long to get there - to me, if someone is a heavy moderator of content but doesn't have much rep, that person doesn't really want to participate in the site.  That's totally fine!  But it's probably not a good sign in terms of their appropriateness to be a moderator.  Again, this isn't to say that nobody with 3k rep could be a good moderator - it's just to say that this is one element that should be weighed.

It's just as unfair, though, to say that someone who has the majority of their participation through actual participation, and not content moderation, is not learning relevant things for moderation.  For one, they're learning by being a part of the community and seeing what is good content.  For two, they clearly know what good content is!  Removing reputation/questions/answers from the picture is clearly removing a relevant piece of information - after all, anyone here think Jon Skeet would be a poor moderator?

I would agree, though, that removing the concept of 'score' entirely, and moving to showing all of the activity in a concise manner - Q's, A's, rep, edits, flags, closes, reviews, etc. - is very reasonable, and solves both problems.  It's entirely possible that there are users who would make good moderators because of extensive experience as content moderators, and users who would make good moderators because of extensive experience as posters - and anywhere in between.  Show everyone all of the information (within reason) and don't have a single score determine the election.

Comment: One problem with rep is for example that it depends on the popularity of the topics. One can write 100 answers in C++, JavaScript and can get much more rep than writing 100 answers in other topics. Rep never was a good to compare different people with. Number of positively scoring question or answers (or top scoring answers) might be better suited to compare different users.

Answer (score 1):

I guess I don't understand why we would change the rules so that ArtofCode has a better shot at becoming moderator, so much so that the rich history of moderators being some of the most active content creators is lost.

I get that there is a large group of people coordinating in chat to cast flags, so it is being put forth as the best bet for moderating (not in my opinion), even though there are bots that cast group flags with their accounts, but I just don't see how that indicates a "strong" candidate.

Moderators should be familiar with interacting with the community, not just taking action against it.

Answer (score -5):

I agree with this. Let's talk for each point:

### Editing - 5 points

I agree with this point, but I think it's too easy to reach 5/5. Multiple people -even with 2k rep for edit- reach 300 edits. I propose to set **100 edits = 1 point**. So, to have 5/5 you need 500 edits. This can be done easily with some others point that we will see after.

### Flagging - 10 points

I agree with this point, but I think we should take in count declined flags, to prevent people that spam of flag which are not useful. I propose to limit it to something like 90% helpful/declined (not counting retracted/disputed/aged), and so have one point with 20 helpful and two declined one. To have 10/10, you need 280 helpful and maximum 25 declined.

Personally, I have 15 declined flag for over 700 helpful, so I think it's clearly possible to easy have a valuable amount.

### Meta Stack Overflow Engagement - 5 points

Nothing to say with this. I agree.

### Reviews - 20 points

Yes, it's an important point which is missed. Some candidates wrote their review amount in their presentation. I think it should really be take in count.

I want to add with the `Editing` point that while reviewing, multiple times a post just needs an edit. Such as with your proposition, it will require 3k rep, people will be able to edit and not only to make review. So, for me, it's easier to reach 500 edits while reviewing.

That's why, if people do reviews, others parts (flag, edit...) will growth, and 500 edits for 5/5 will not be so hard to reach, except if people just start reviewing for this election/just before.

### Reach score limit

I want to add a new point: In the last election, 4 of 6 candidates had 39 or 40/40. If we really want to make something that should help people to prioritize the activity of candidate, that's not really helpful to have everyone with the same score (or with 1/2 point of difference). I think it should have a minimum, but don't have a limit. For example, if someone makes 1,000 helpful flags, he/she will have the same score than someone that makes 300 helpful flags. This can be beneficial for old people, but it will just show that the candidate is active over the time, which is an important things: we don't want a moderator that left one week after his/her election.

To don't show as "60/40" which will be very confusing, I propose two ways:

1. Two values, which are shown as:

- Score: 35/40
- Bonus score: 25/100

2. More information (some candidates of last election write them in their explanation of why they should be a moderator):

- Score: 35/40
- Review: 100/100
- Edit: 80/100
- etc

The objective should be to show a score, and not just the amount of review or edit because with this, we could count as we want to, especially about review (for example, in your post you count LQP reviews differently).

PS: With these new ways and in 28 rep, I will have 40/40 points (which was not the case before)

Comment: I agree with taking declined flags into account, but 90% is _way_ to low. If you're going to be the one responsible for handling the flags, then reviewing every 10th wrong is a no-go for me. I much rather see that go up to 97/98%. And maybe count every declined flag as -20 helpful flags for reaching the points threshold. Of course over time the helpful% of a user will (hopefully) increase, so it might be worth to only take the helpful% of the last year or so into account, to undo mistakes made long ago that are no longer representative.

Comment: *"90% helpful/declined"* No, I don't like it. We don't want people to be afraid of casting flags. Even 50% is a good ratio because that means that you still care about the site enough to flag issues. Some users are already so afraid of getting declined flag that they prefer to not flag anything. We don't want that outcome

Comment: It's funny: one comment want to make it as 97%+ and the other want to reduce at 50%.  Yes I don't want to be afraid, but 10% of fail is pretty fine, such as lot of flag are in disputed which should not be count as I said. Declined are globally mod one like NAA or spam. And if they don't flag anything, they will have low score. And only candidate for mod can be afraid, people that should know which flag raise

Comment: Flag ratios are stupid. You can get a very high ratio by using SEDE and flagging thanks comments and link-only posts and be fairly certain they'll be marked helpful, while spam/rudeness/voting patterns are more tricky and way more relevant imo. They certainly should not become part of any score.

Comment: @ErikA On top of that, for someone like me to improve my ratio, would be extremely difficult. I am at 99.6% and it's unlikely to change much any time soon. To offset all my declined flags I would need a streak of thousands of helpful flags.

Comment: @Dharman You have an high ratio which is difficult to change because you made lot of flag, and you are not flag-banned. With bad ratio, you will be banned, and so don't have so much flag and so can change it. Also, the Ivar's solution can help (to take only recent flag).

Comment: @Dharman I agree that we shouldn't scare users away from flagging content, but afaict the answer is referring to criteria for moderator candidates. If one is running for moderator, I don't think a track record of 90% helpful flags is unreasonable. Certainly 50% is too low; I would seriously reconsider voting for a candidate who gets half their flags wrong.

Comment: The part starting with *"but with this amount"* is partly incomprehensible. Can you fix?

Comment: @PeterMortensen sorry, I misunderstand something in the original post for this sentence. I remove it because it doesn't make sens with context.

Answer (score -15):

I'd like to see **endorsements** contribute to the score, or be listed as a separate metric. The piece of information that I personally find most useful for determining my vote is the comments about candidates from the nomination phase. That information is difficult for users to find by final phase of the election.  I'd like to see something like:

> #### Candidate A
>
> - Reputation: 20k+
> - Candidate score: 35/40
> - Endorsements: 345

Clicking on the endorsements metric would show a list of users that have endorsed that candidate, possibly with a comment about why from each user. It would be great if the list could be sorted with endorsements from existing moderators and highest reputation users first.

There would have to be some criteria for who could endorse candidates. Maybe only users with 5k, 10k or 20k reputation could do so.

I'd imagine that if you were eligible to endorse candidates you could endorse any number of them, or at least as many as there are open moderator positions.

Comment: Endorsements: nepotism counter. On the other hand, isn't the voting process of an election literally the same?

Comment: Voting is private, endorsements are public. The criteria for who gets to vote should be different from who gets to endorse.  I'd also value comments that come with endorsements.  I'd like to know why you might endorse a candidate.

Comment: "Endorsements" - this is what votes are for. We don't need to know who Jon Skeet voted for. Jon Skeet can be wrong. I don't want any user to vote based on how someone else is voting, thank you very much... that's not how votes should be cast.

Comment: "I'm heavily invested in this  site and I vouch for this candidate" says a lot to me.  Any one endorsement can be wrong, but I'd like to see which candidates gets lots of them.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller if it's about number overall for you rather than a single person, then it seems like _who_ is behind the numbers isn't as relevant... and at that point, that's again exactly what vote/score conveys. If it matters, we already _have_ endorsements of a sort in the nominations page: people regularly leave comments under nomination posts saying things like "this user is excellent at X Y Z and will be a great moderator!" -- those are signed and dated by the author.

Comment: I would be interested in seeing endorsements from one particular group of people: the existing moderators.  They know what's involved in moderating better than anyone, and quite likely have more visibility into what the candidate is doing behind the scenes (e.g., are they a valuable flagger?).

Answer (score -37):

## I dislike this proposal

Things are better the way they are now. There is a bias here as the Room Owner for "Stack Overflow Close Vote Reviewers (SOCVR)". This room does not exemplify the kind of moderation I want and I don't want to select for people that *do moderation*. I want expert users to moderate, not a class of moderators that isolate themselves from the community and are only occasional users.

If you want to get better quality candidates, open up elections to all people and let the community decide. Currently, candidates must meet outrageous criteria that factors in *other sites* on the network than the on they're applying to moderate.

The idea that you're biasing a potential moderators expertise with something that isn't subject matter expertise just waters down the candidate you're likely to get. I'd rather see **EVERYONE** with over 50,000 exp (or, 100,000 exp) on the site have all the privileges of moderator, and then we remove the special class, the junta, and formality. Moderation should be transparent and done by the community, not by people aspiring to get jobs in product advocacy, or community outreach.

Comment: Everyone with high rep? There are many high rep users here who I would not trust with the ability to make unilateral moderation decisions, much less let them have access to my private information.

Comment: Then make them vote on it, like we do with closure/deletes. And, as far your information, I don't think that's a productive conversation. I don't trust the current moderators with my "private information." I have to suck it up currently. The only question is who is _more_ trustworthy. The SOCVR junta of aspiring community relations professionals, or the people who are here **NOT** to moderate the site but to merely be productive members of it.

Comment: `moderate the site == being a productive member of it`...

Comment: _"Currently, candidates must meet outrageous criteria"_ It is not outrageous to those who are indeed supposed to be interested in _moderating_, because those would already have a stake in curating the site.
_"Moderation should be transparent and done by the community, not by people aspiring to get jobs in product advocacy, or community outreach."_ I don't believe people who truly understand the role of an elected moderator would say this.

Comment: Are you sure you are talking about elected moderators here? I don't really understand your suggestion. What does SOCVR have to do with elections? Why do you think the moderators we elect are isolated from the community? What does that even mean? Do you think that elected moderators are not handling Spam and rude content appropriately?

Comment: @E_net4standswithUkraine it is highly outrageous to tell someone they can't run for an election on StackOverflow, because of their behavior on a remote site like [ubuntu.se] and then to sell the solution of getting a crop of moderators that are active on **NO** sites but cast close and delete votes when requested by their friends in an unofficial channel.

Comment: I think you have never visited that chat room. SOCVR as the name suggests only deals with SO. It doesn't accept any requests from other sites in the network. Users who frequent that chat room have no special powers when it comes to electing moderators. It's just a priority channel for Close vote review queue. You can bring certain posts that need faster closure to the attention of other users. It's not a cult and claiming that it is one is offensive. Users like you and I go to that room because they care about this site.

Comment: Moderators are SMEs in many areas. Last time I checked we had elected moderators in most of our most popular tags. I don't know who you would want to see elected that would make you happy

Comment: @Dharman re-read what I said. I didn't say SOCVR tells others that they can't run for an election. SOCVR does not; but, a dialog box on the nomination does. The problem with that is it selects for people who are not active on the _network_, because activity elsewhere increase the chance of getting suspended elsewhere which means you can't run _anywhere_. It creates a shortage of SME moderators.

Comment: re: _I don't know who you would want to see elected that would make you happy_ Great question. **I'd like to see all moderators have 100k rep (simply to exclude myself so there is no claim of self-interest), and that they have to maintain a score of 10 (answers + questions) a month.** That's the activity and expertise I want involved in moderation. I'd prefer it to be fully automatic with no election required. Shy of that, I'm more interested in removing moderators (make them stand for election) than appointing more from the same clique.

Comment: It is clear that you have a problem with moderated platforms, and as such you want reputation farmers and care bears to be moderators instead of those who would rather maintain quality standards and uphold the site's code of conduct with seriousness. The only word left to say is... no.

Comment: This is not a serious proposal for consideration for numerous reasons, chief of which is likely the total infeasibility of Stack Overflow the company entering into legally-binding moderator agreements (not to mention time-consuming on-boarding) with everyone who reaches some arbitrary reputation threshold.

Comment: "*The problem with that is it selects for people who are not active on the network, because activity elsewhere increase the chance of getting suspended elsewhere which means you can't run anywhere. It creates a shortage of SME moderators.*" This is spurious reasoning. The vast majority of users who are active on multiple sites are never suspended on any of them. Likewise, the people who nominate for and tend to get elected on Stack Overflow are the kind of users who are _least_ likely to incur a suspension... here or anywhere else.

Comment: But the above scenario is irrelevant, anyway, given that there exists an avenue for redress: you can contact the CM team and request an exception to the penalty if you feel like your suspension on another site was incorrect or should not be factored into your eligibility to run for moderator on a site.

Comment: @TylerH good luck with that. I got suspended on [security.se] by an Israeli for having the nick "Israel is an Apartheid State" he said it was advocating genocide (literally). I wrote to them, and they wouldn't let me stand in an election. Yet, I could have that nick on other sites on the same network.

Comment: @TylerH re _"The vast majority of users who are active on multiple sites are never suspended on any of them. Likewise, the people who nominate for and tend to get elected on Stack Overflow are the kind of users who are least likely to incur a suspension... here or anywhere else."_ That's actually the spurious reasoning. You can't run if you've incurred a suspension (within the past year). You can not argue they're those elected are the least likely to be suspended when those suspended can **NOT** run.

Comment: Frankly I think expecting users to ask and answer some `n` questions a month is more outrageous than the current requirements. At the risk of beating a dead horse to a pulp, domain knowledge in a language is totally irrelevant to the skills and tasks an elected moderator takes on. The pool of users who are grok the theory of moderation and also who answer multiple times a week and have hundreds of thousands of reputation points is a rather small one... it's _much_ smaller than the pool of users who just answer multiple times a week and have hundreds of thousands of reputation points.

Comment: @NOWARWITHRUSSIA I'm arguing those who are suspended are not likely to be great candidates, which from the current sample size of one seems to be a fairly accurate statement. Your anecdote above seems to indicate the process is working as designed. You were able to bring your case for review and the review was completed with the result of your request being denied. A fair chance does not always mean you get what you want.

Comment: Well, let's keep in things context here TylerH. You have 20,300 rep. Just 300 rep over the amount needed to moderate and you're a "Member & Room Owner" of SOCVR. You're here to moderate. [**YOU HAVE NEVER ASKED A SINGLE "GOOD QUESTION"**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2756409/tylerh?tab=badges) on a site devoted to questions and answers. You're exactly the type of person I don't want to see elected. You've asked 12 questions in 8 years. You don't know what the experience of using the site is like.

Comment: @NOWARWITHRUSSIA Actually I have asked several "good questions", I just receive revenge downvotes on a regular basis by users with an axe to grind. As for reputation needed to moderate, I have been performing moderation tasks in some regard since 2000 reputation or so when the review queues were first opened to me. I'm here to contribute to the site, and I do so in numerous ways: answering, asking, editing, closing, reopening, deleting, undeleting, contributing to Meta discussions, filing bug reports, filing feature requests, etc.

Comment: That you consider only one metric while ignoring context for even that metric says all anyone needs to know about how un-serious this proposal is.

Comment: Contributions to the site are not only new questions. Contributions can be all these things that TylerH listed in previous comment. In fact, a moderator should focus less on asking questions and answering and more on handling flags and exceptional scenarios. This is why we elect them for. We don't elect people to ask questions. A user who closed, flagged, deleted many times is a good candidate because they know what needs to be done to keep the site clean and useful for visitors. A help vampire that only asks questions would be a terrible moderator.

Comment: @NOWARWITHRUSSIA Please don't discuss individual user's moderation actions on this post. The question even explicitly mentions not making this about individual users.